# How do I click on expand & collapse button in selenium by using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I want to click on expand button to view the menu items.

```
@Then("^click on set up$")
    public void click_on_set_up() throws Throwable {       
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn-header pull-right")).click();
       }
```

This code isnot working. Please tell me if there is a way to click on expand and collapse button.

Comment: please add the source code of your project

Answer (score 0):

Use action class :-

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By."Your Locator");
actions.moveToElement(mainMenu);

WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By."Your Locator");
actions.moveToElement(subMenu);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

Hope it will help you :)